# Code to export a function in R

Tags: r, package

Is it possible to export a function in R by evaluating an expression? What I would like to write something like

```
my.great.fun = function(x) x
export(my.great.fun)
```

in a R file in a package and have my.great.fun exported.
Then you can evaluate that in a loop, conditionally, define family of functions concisely etc. The immediate application would be generating and exporting setters and getters for an S4 class in two lines of code as opposed to as many lines as there are slots. I saw the package `R.MethodsS3`, but the export option doesn't seem to do anything other than setting an attribute, ditto the now un-exported export function therein. setGeneric for S4 doesn't have a similar option. I am a fairly navigated R developer with several packages under my belt, so it doesn't help to point me to standard documentation about the `NAMESPACE` file. `roxygen` `@export` is not a solution because it doesn't work in loops, is not in the language, is not first, second or even third class in R. It seems to me we can create functions, generics of S3 and S4 flavors, methods of S3 and S4 flavors all in the language, and the only bit that is missing is the export part: omission or hole in my knowledge? Thanks

Comment: Does `exportPattern()` not work for your purposes? Decorate any variables you do not wish to export (e.g. with a leading ".") and export everything else (e.g. `exportPattern("^[^\\.]")`).

Comment: Brilliant workaround. In conjunction with `assign` it allows me to export dynamically. I hate to have to decorate names -- what is this, python? -- but if nothing else emerges, this is a possibility. I'd rather use a suffix because it doesn't mess up completion -- I don't have to remember if a function is exported or not. So that would be `exportPattern("[^\\.]$" )` if I remember correctly

Answer (score 0):

You can add the function to an environment when calling export. Then in .onLoad you attach the environment. For instance, see `rex_mode` in package `rex`. Reading packages written by the R intelligentsia pays off.